# joomla 2.5 - bootstrap based template - elegant way to set up module width

Tags: php, templates, twitter-bootstrap, joomla2.5

I've created my own bootstrap based template with joomla 2.5.
I've planned two optional modules on a row inside a bar (which must hide if there are not modules inside it), but i want them to occupy the whole row if they are not shown together.
My code is simple and it works perfectly, but since I hate writing unnecessary lines, I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to achieve this goal (or if I can avoid one or more check inside mycode...)
Here's my code

```
<?php if(($this->countModules('position-16'))|| ($this->countModules('position-17'))): ?>
<div class="evo-showcase">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
        <?php if($this->countModules('position-16')):?>
            <?php if($this->countModules('position-17')):?>
            <div  class="span6">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-16" style="none" />
            </div>
            <div  class="span6">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-17" style="none" />
            </div>
            <?php else :?>
            <div  class="span12">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-16" style="xhtml" />
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php else :?>
            <div  class="span12">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-17" style="xhtml" />
            </div>  
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>      
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$span = 0;
if($this->countModules('position-16') and $this->countModules('position-17')){
    $span = 6;
} else if ($this->countModules('position-16') or $this->countModules('position-17')) {
    $span = 12;
}
?>

<?php if($span > 0):?>
<div class="evo-showcase">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">

            <?php if($this->countModules('position-16')):?>
            <div class="span<?php echo $span;?>">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-16" style="none" />
            </div>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if($this->countModules('position-17')):?>
            <div class="span<?php echo $span;?>">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-17" style="none" />
            </div>
            <?php endif;?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Yes, you got it! 
If I code it this way i can move to the head the first check. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$spanClass=(($this->countModules('position-16')&&($this->countModules('position-17'))?6:12;
?>
<?php if($this->countModules('position-16')):?>
<div  class="span<?php echo $spanClass;?>">
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-16" style="none" />
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($this->countModules('position-17')):?>
<div  class="span<?php echo $spanClass;?>">
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-17" style="none" />
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Your code is pretty good too, but the code related to the bar remains (empty) in the page even if both modules are missing.. Thanks a lot ^^